# Trying to use emmet with a react app in vs code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using Visual Studio Code and creating a React App.  I understand that Vsc comes with Emmet but it does not work with my React App.  I have tried putting the following code in settings.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact",
"xml": {
  "attr_quotes": "single"
 }
 },
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

Comment: do you use sublime-babel ? If yes this cause a problem

Comment: Hello, Can you mark the answer from @Damjan which is correct. It will be helpful for others and confusing for new comers.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Add this to settings JSON:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Comment: I also had to add `"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true` or I found adding emmet siblings with the + character did not work properly.

Answer (score 40):

In case the marked answer dont work!

In VS Code open settings using command:

On PC: `Ctrl + ,`

On Mac: `Command + ,`

---

Be sure `workspace` is selected

[image]

Search Emmet, scroll down to `Emmet Include Language` and open `settings.JSON` file

[image]

Paste the following code and save the file. Reload `VS CODE` and it will work!:

```
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
   
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  }
}
```

---

## Updated 2022

Add item and and its value like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

On PC: `Ctrl + ,`

On Mac: `Command + ,`

Make Sure you have added item and value like shown in screenshot below -

[image]

Answer (score 5):

install Extension Emmet

go to **setting.json** then add this:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact",
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go into your `settings.json` file and inside the "configuration" object paste this:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{
  "emmet.excludeLanguages": ["markdown"],

  "emmet.includeLanguages": {

    "javascript": "javascriptreact"

  }
}
```

Add this to your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting or press `Ctrl + ,` then setting.json then add this:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact"
},
```

Comment: This is best way to change any vscode configuration according to project

Answer (score 0):

To enable Emmet, we need to include the language setting in `settings.json`.
For both JavaScript `.jsx` and TypeScript `.tsx`, add the following config in VS Code user settings:

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact"
}
```