# Nav.navbar autocompletion not working in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2UBjN5ER4s&t=653s) React tutorial. At 10:21, he uses the shortcut `nav.navbar` to create a nav with className "navbar." However, when I try to do this in my code editor (VS Code) it doesn't autocomplete.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use emmet with a react app in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750263/trying-to-use-emmet-with-a-react-app-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

Coincidently I was following the same tutorial and got curious about that as well. It seems like VS Code comes with the command that expand Emmet abbreviations using *tab* disabled. You need to go into VS Code settings and enable this option.

You can do that by going into the settings file and adding the line `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`. Another option is from the settings menu within VS Code (File>Preferences>Settings) and use the search box to look for `Emmet: Show Suggestions As Snippets`, then check the checkbox.

More information:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

[Emmet expand abbreviation doesn't work in Visual Studio Code with the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083159/emmet-expand-abbreviation-doesnt-work-in-visual-studio-code-with-the-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

on VScode settings search "emmet", look for "Emmet: Include Languages"
add item:
item: javascript
value: javascriptreact